# can't get my location

Tags: java, android, gps, location

i tried for hours to get my location,but that does not work...
i did it with a video guide step by step, the emulator is shot down while i run the application.
I already try lot of things like this solution.
And the GPS is enable in the virtual device... It's not working on my phone too. So this is my code

```
package com.example.idanhay.safebox;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class settings extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button;

    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bloc);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvloc);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.append("/n" + location.getAltitude() + "" + location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(settings.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 10);

                return;
            }
        } else
            configurationButten();

    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grandresult) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (grandresult.length > 0 && grandresult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    configurationButten();
                return;

        }
    }

    private void configurationButten() {

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(settings.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                         // TODO: Consider calling
                         //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                         // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                         //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                         //                                          int[] grantResults)
                         // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                         // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                         return;
                     }
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 4000, 0, locationListener);
            }
        });
/*
```

Comment: i have this in the manifest too.               <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: What is the problem **exactly**. Do you have an exception, is it the wrong location, nothing happening...

Comment: What does not work? What error do you get? (Also, you should move your comment to the question by editing it.)

Comment: the app trying to run, but its stoped

Comment: If your app is crashing, you should post the exception and stack trace in your question